# Same question to multiple remote users with different login

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine

I am very new to Google App Engine and Python. I am building a web application using Python and Django which is based on questions and multiple answers. Once the users are logged in to the website, they will be provided with random questions from a datastore.

What my requirement is, if certain users want to form a group so that they all can get the same random questions at the same time to answer, is this possible? Without forming the group, each user gets different random questions on their end.

Comment: I'm sure it is possible, but you should explain the problem more precisely.  Do the users in a group get the same question at the same time, or do they get just the same sequence of questions?  If they get the same question at the same time, what determines when a different question is shown?  When it is answered correctly?  To provide a good answer, you need to define the problem clearly and precisely.

Comment: Thanks Robert.Glad you provided such a quick reply!! Yes the user in the same group will have to get the same question at the same time. I am not sure how I am going to handle the provided response but ultimately my aim is to gather answers from each user and compare the given answer for each question with the correct answer which is stored in datastore column. By this way I want to provide them their individual score along with their competitors in the group. I am using random function to randomly select question from the datastore but I am not sure from here how should I proceed. Thanks

Comment: @user562802: Please **update** the question.  Please do not add comments to the question.  "Yes the user in the same group will have to get the same question at the same time"?  How?  How will two simultaneous transactions decide which question for both transactions?

Comment: Hi S.Lott, updated question. Well i am not sure how this is going to implemented thats why in my post I inquired about the feasibility of the question. Excuse me if the question seems odd to you people but this is where currently I am scratching my head.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this should be possible.  Your solution might look something like this:

1. A user creates a new group.

   1. You generate some random questions and store them in a list for that group.
2. More users join that group.
3. You start showing the questions to the users by selecting the first question in that groups list.
4. Once all users have correctly answered the question, you remove the question from the groups list and show the next question.

Comment: yes Robert,this seems very good solution.I will definitely try on by this method. I am marking your question as accepted. My first experience with Stack overflow is very good :-)

Comment: @user562802, make sure you 1) use Appstats (http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/appstats.html) and 2) lookup some solutions for efficiently select random records (it takes pre-planning!).

Comment: Nice..this link will be very useful since I started learning google app engine and django three weeks back..appreciate your help